# dotless: how to process a list of LESS files using dotless.Compiler.exe

Tags: css, msbuild, msbuild-task, dotless

I wanted to know how to process a list of LESS files using the exe binaries, for example:

```
./dotless.Compiler.exe -m *.less
```

Right now I only can do individual files, but can't do wildcard.

The reason why I asked about this is that I want to create a target in MSBuild, which is to process an item collection (which is a list of files). I couldn't find a way to loop a task in side MSBuild. If anyone knows how to loop a task for each file, that would solve my problem too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `ItemGroup` to get a list of files like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyFiles Include="[path to less files]\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Call the compiler once for each file by using `%(MyFiles.FullPath)` syntax (also known as [Task Batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))

```
<Target Name="CompileLess">
   <Exec Command="$(dotLessCompiler) -m %(MyFiles.FullPath)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Do you mean the line can be converted to this command line: ./dotless.Compiler.exe -m style1.less style2.less style3.less? I don't think it will work as expected.

Comment: No, it will be executed one file at a time. See my updated answer.